# Changing TextureRegion of Sprite to one from another Atlas fails sometimes - LIBGDX

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I have a lot of stars (an array of sprites) that I draw on my background. But when the user starts another level it may need to get those stars' Texture from another Atlas. just before level restart I change all star sprite textures with setRegion, but sometimes 2 or 3 out of 500 stars don't change the texture properly and are drawn on the screen like a black rectangle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < stars.size() - 1; i++)
{
    stars.get(i).setRegion(another_Atlas.findRegion("star_type1"));
}
```

How can I make sure all star sprite textures are changed properly?

Comment: Did you bind the new atlas before trying to use it?

Comment: How do I bind it? I just load it from the AssetManager with the AssetManager.load and AssetManager.get methods.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html), in particular the part at the top

Comment: Thank you! It worked now! Put it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have bound your texture before you try to use it, by calling `GLTexture.bind()` (more on this [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html))